# Spring MVC - creating an httprequest with java for a controller

Tags: java, spring, web-services, apache, rest

here is one controller i got on my web application:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =     MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseDTO createAccount(@RequestBody PlayerAccountDTO playerAccountDTO,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    this.playerService.createAccount(playerAccountDTO);

    return new ResponseDTO();
}
```

This controller is being called via ajax using post and passing a json and jackson mapper takes care for it to arrive as a POJO (Nice!)

What i would like to do now is:
In a different web application i would like to call with http post request passing PlayerAccountDTO  to this exact controller and ofcourse recieve the ResponseDTO.

I would like that to be as simple as possible.

Is it possible to achieve that?  here is my wishfull solution (a service on a different web app):

```
public ResponseDTO createAccountOnADifferentWebApp() {

    PlayerAccountDTO dto = new PlayerAccountDTO(...);

    ResponseDTO result = httpRequestPost(url, dto, ResponseDTO.class);

            return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your web server doesn't receive a `PlayerAccountDTO` object. It receives an HTTP request with a body that (likely) contains a JSON object. The Spring web application tries to deserialize that JSON into a `PlayerAccountDTO` object which it passes to your handler method.

So what you want to do is use an HTTP client which serializes your `PlayerAcocuntDTO` on the client side into some JSON which you send in an HTTP request.

Check out [`RestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) which is a Spring HTTP client and uses the same `HttpMessageConverter` objects that Spring uses to serialize and deserialize objects in `@ResponseBody` annotated methods and `@RequestBody` annotated parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [commons-http-client library](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html)